# Getting to see Commons Logging debug messages in J2SE app

Tags: java, debugging, logging, apache-commons-logging

In a standalone J2SE application I'm using some library code that uses `Log.debug` from Commons Logging to output some debug information. My app currently has no logging configuration whatsoever. By default I see some log messages in *stdout*, but not the debug ones. What's the quickest way to enable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use some implementation of commons logging like log4j and [configure it](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html).